# Client 443/HTTPS -> Virtual IP -> HA Proxy 80/HTTP and 443/HTTPS SSL terminaison -> Varnish 81/HTTP -> 82/HTTPS and 442/HTTPS Apache

Tags: haproxy, varnish

I posted the same question on stackoverflow but someone adviced to post it here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77885246/client-443-https-virtual-ip-ha-proxy-80-http-and-443-https-ssl-terminaison

At home, I have 1 hosted server with some websites, using Virtualmin (great tool!) and everything is working fine with HTTPS, HTTP...even behind my internet router, using NAT by forwarding ports 80 and 443 to my web server.

Client 443/HTTPS -> my Internet Router NAT -> 80/HTTP or 443/HTTPS Apache

I am doing some improvments by adding a load balancer HA Proxy in front of Apache : working fine.

Client 443/HTTPS -> my Internet Router NAT -> **HA Proxy 443/HTTPS SSL terminaison** -> 82/HTTP or 442/HTTPS Apache (192.168.0.40)

That means my websites are still available on HTTPS protocol but on port 442

And I even added keepalived and it's working fine :

Client 443/HTTPS -> my Internet Router NAT -> **KEEPALIVED IP ADDRESS** -> HA Proxy 443/HTTPS SSL terminaison -> 82/HTTP or 442/HTTPS Apache

Now, I would like to add the Web Caching Varnish. As you may know, the free version of Varnish does not support HTTPS. It's not a problem for me because I have HA Proxy that handles SSL terminaison.
What I want to do is to set Varnish behind HA Proxy and in front of Apache.

Client 443/HTTPS -> my Internet Router NAT -> KEEPALIVED IP ADDRESS -> HA Proxy 443/HTTPS SSL terminaison -> **Varnish 81/HTTP** -> 82/HTTP or 442/HTTPS Apache

But it does not work...
When I try to acccess to my website using HTTPS, for instance https://myexemple.com, the homepage is loaded but all other static files not...
Looking into the page network inspector (F12 from the browser), I can see that these static files are served using HTTP (see attached screenshot).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT2es.jpg)

Just installed wordpress for this website, nothing else.

Did somebody have a similar issue or maybe succceed in implementing an architecture schema like mine:

Client 443/HTTPS -> KEEPALIVED IP ADDRESS -> HA Proxy 443/HTTPS SSL terminaison -> **Varnish 81/HTTP** -> 82/HTTP or 442/HTTPS Apache

In general, how do you handle HTTPS when using Varnish?
Especially with Wordpress: in the backend, we have to specify the URL of the website (i.e. https://kmx.ovh in my case)?
Thank you

Well, I tried to setup Varnish behind HA Proxy and in front of my Apache websites, see configuration below :

Here is the configuration of my HA Proxy (quite simple):

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
        ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
        ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 no-tls-tickets
        tune.ssl.default-dh-param 4096

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        option http-server-close
        timeout connect 5s
        timeout client  50s
        timeout server  50s
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


frontend https
        description "HA Proxy"
        bind *:80
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/cert/
        mode http
        option httplog
        option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
        http-response set-header MON-LOADBALANCER "HTTPS HA Proxy 40"
        default_backend varnish_pool

backend varnish_pool
        description 'Varnish backends pool'
        balance roundrobin
        mode http
        http-response set-header X-Frame-Options DENY
        http-response set-header X-XSS-Protection 1;mode=block
        http-response set-header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        http-response set-header Referrer-Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade
        default-server inter 15s fall 3 rise 2
        option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1
        http-check expect status 200
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
        server 40-80 192.168.0.40:81
```

And here is my Varnish configuration file (really basic...):

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "192.168.0.40";
    .port = "82";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = default;
    set req.http.Host = req.http.host;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.MonX-Cache = "via Varnish cache 40";
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
        set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}
```

And the Varnish service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
LimitNOFILE=131072

# Locked shared memory - should suffice to lock the shared memory log
# (varnishd -l argument)
# Default log size is 80MB vsl + 1M vsm + header -> 82MB
# unit is bytes
LimitMEMLOCK=85983232
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
          -j unix,user=vcache \
          -F \
          -a :81 \
          -T localhost:6082 \
          -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
          -S /etc/varnish/secret \
          -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/varnishreload
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: set WordPress home URL to https://

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler and faster to just use nginx instead of haproxy + varnish?

Comment: @symcbean - but then, you'd be using *nginx*

Comment: Your traffic flow is going from https to http and then again to https,looks almost like a man in the middle attack. Why are you making it yourself so difficult, have you considered if the caching of HAProxy is also sufficient for you.

Comment: @Turdie : yes, I know, that's why I ask if somebody succeeded in solving this problem? but probably that finally I will shift to only hTTP for Apache backend, if nobody solved that! ;-)

Comment: On GitHub somebody solved it apparently https://gist.github.com/sys0dm1n/b07b8a783fd1931a4118aeca42e13e2e

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1: ensure HAProxy sends the X-Forwarded-Proto header

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77885246/client-443-https-virtual-ip-ha-proxy-80-http-and-443-https-ssl-terminaison/77885399?noredirect=1#comment137311196_77885399 where you also asked the question, I would advise you to start by adding the following header to your HAProxy backend configuration:

```
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
```

## Step 2: make WordPress understand X-Forwarded-Proto

Now that I know you're using WordPress, you have to inform WordPress about the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, because it doesn't support it out-of-the-box.

As mentioned on https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/mixed-content-err-too-many-redirects-wordpress-varnish/#checking-the-x-forwarded-proto-header-in-wordpress, add the following code to your `wp-config.php`:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && 
    strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

## Step 3: create cache variations based on the X-Forwarded-Proto header

To make sure Varnish caches HTTPS & HTTP responses in different cache objects, you have to alter the `vcl_hash` subroutine and add `X-Forwarded-Proto` as a variation.

Here's the code to do that:

```
sub vcl_hash {
    if(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
}
```

However, to ensure proper caching in Varnish, you should use a specialized VCL file. I suggest you read https://www.varnishsoftware.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-wordpress/ and use that VCL code, along with a purging plugin.

Comment: Hello @thijs Feryn, thank you for your advice. I will try but from scratch: I am reinstalling Ubuntu server 22.04 on my server and I will install one by one (again) all the components with these configurations. I will keep you up to date